# Regex to get Java import statements

Tags: java, regex, string

I am writing a Java program to read other Java source files and pull out there `import` statements:

```
package com.me.myapp

import blah.example.dog.client.Fizz;
import blah.example.cat.whiskers.client.Buzz;
import blah.example.shared.Foo;
import blah.example.server.Bar;
...etc.
```

I want the regex to return anything starting with `import blah.example.` and that has `client` in the package name after that. Hence the regex would pick up `Fizz` and `Buzz` in the example above, but not `Foo` or `Bar`.

My best attempt is:

```
String regex = "import blah.example*client*";
if(someString.matches(regex))
    // Do something
```

This regex isn't throwing an exception, but itsn't working. Where am I going wrong with it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't reliably parse source code with regular expressions. You'd be better off using [an actual java parser](http://code.google.com/p/javaparser/).

Comment: @BradMace Good point. It would be impossible to, say, reliably skip imports that were commented out in a multiline comment block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dot in a regex is a special character that means "any character". You have to escape a literal dot, and you want a dot before your * (meaning any number of occurrences of any character):

```
"import blah\\.example.*client.*"
```

The expression as you had it:

```
"import blah.example*client*"
```

Meant "import blah", followed by a single wildcard character, followed by "exampl", then 0 or more e's, then "clien", then 0 or more t's. It would match, say, "import blahxexampleeeeeclientttt" or "import blah examplclien".

Also, the (fixed) regex will still match things like "import blah.example2.notclient" and "/* import blah.example.client; */", so you still want to enforce the location of literal dots around client and the start of line, e.g. (unescaped for clarity, remember to escape slashes in string constants):

```
^import blah\.example(\.[^.]+)*\.client(\.[^.]+)*;
```

Where the sequence (unescaped for clarity):

```
(\.[^.]+)*
```

Matches any number of individual ".xxx" path components.

Note, however, like Brad Mace points out in the comments, regular expressions alone still aren't reliable for this. You don't have a good way to skip, e.g. a bunch of import statements commented out by a /* */ multiline comment.

Comment: You can use `[^.]`. Dot loses its special meaning in there.

Comment: Thanks @Jason C (+1) - however `String regex = "^import blah\.example(\.[^.]+)*\.client(\.[^.]+)*;";` gives me a compiler error...

Comment: That's why I said "remember to escape slashes in string constants"! Replace each \ with \\ :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try with `^import blah[.]example[.](\\w+[.])*client[.]\\w+;$` with MULTILINE flag to make ^ and $ match also start and end of new lines.

Here is some demo:

```
String data = "package com.me.myapp\n\nimport blah.example.dog.client.Fizz;\nimport blah.example.cat.whiskers.client.Buzz;\nimport blah.example.shared.Foo;\nimport blah.example.server.Bar;";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
        "^import blah[.]example[.](\\w+[.])*client[.]\\w+;$",
        Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher m = p.matcher(data);
while (m.find())
    System.out.println(m.group());
```

Output

```
import blah.example.dog.client.Fizz;
import blah.example.cat.whiskers.client.Buzz;
```

---

You can also use the similar regex to check if it matches your strings/lines

```
String data = "package com.me.myapp\n\nimport blah.example.dog.client.Fizz;\nimport blah.example.cat.whiskers.client.Buzz;\nimport blah.example.shared.Foo;\nimport blah.example.server.Bar;";

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(data);
while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
    String line=scanner.nextLine();
    if (line.matches("import blah[.]example[.](\\w+[.])*client[.]\\w+;")){
        System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: In this answer I assume that OP have formatted code without spaces at start or after `;`, also without import statements in comments. In case it is not clean code regex will need to change a little :)

Comment: You actually wouldn't be able to detect if an import statement was in a multiline comment without doing some basic amount of additional parsing.

Comment: @JasonC with look-around I could try but yes, it would not be easy task and should be done with parser rather than regex.

Comment: @Pshemo With disclaimer! We all can add: Ctrl + Shift + F required in Eclipse :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `someString` is one of the lines from the Java source code

*Java String*

```
"import\\s+blah\\.example(?:\\.\\w+)*\\.client(?:\\.\\*|(?:\\.\\w+)*);"
```

*Regex*

```
import\s+blah\.example(?:\.\w+)*\.client(?:\.\*|(?:\.\w+)*);
```

Comment: You can use repeating patterns of (\.[^\.]+)* to match path components.

Comment: @JasonC I actually wanted to just fix OP's regex so that it doesn't fail to match *valid* imports. But, this soon became find the regex validator for Java import statements! :)

Comment: Yes, that happened to me too.

Answer (score 1):

threating sources as text files can be problematic....

i would try the following approaches instead:
 * using javac processor framework to integrate your matcher into the compiler
 * using the ASM library

Answer (score 0):

Regex may parse src incorrectly, eg commented out imports

```
/*
import blah.example.dog.client.Fizz;
import blah.example.cat.whiskers.client.Buzz;
*/
```

or not formatted code

```
import blah.example.dog.client.Fizz; import blah.example.cat.whiskers.client.Buzz;
```